# Cant call a segue in code (Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, segue

I have a few views embedded in a navigation controller.

I've created a few segues (some from buttons to other view controllers, some from one view controller to another one.

for example I have a segue (Show) from one button to a view controller called name2, when I press the button it works great, but when I try to call it programmatically the app crashes and gives an error.

This is how I call the segue on **ViewController1**

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("name2", sender: self)
```

this is from **ViewController1** to **ViewController2**

I also have a segue that is connected not to a button but from vc1 to vc2, gives the same error.

This is the strange error I get:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (ViewController2) has no segue with identifier 'name2''
```

I tried cleaning the product and also reseting the simulator.

A screen shot of my storyboard

[image: storyboard]

A screen of the identity inspector of viewcontroller1 (it is actually called ViewController in my project)

[image: Identity Inspector]

A screen shot of the segue (name3) [image: segue]

The options of the segue :
[image]

**Edit:**
I found that when I connect a button as an IBAction and then call `performSegueWithIdentifier("LogIn", sender: self)` from the button it works correctly.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the answer is that I'm pretty dumb,
Whenever I was creating new ViewControllers, I was subclassing `ViewController` which was my first ViewController, instead of `UIViewController` which made it run recursivly.

Answer (score 2):

Do not connect your Button in Storyboard Editor to the other segue (when you want to call the performWithSegue function within your ViewController1) - just connect the first ViewController to the second One.

Then you can use

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("name2", sender: self)
```

within your ViewController1 class.

Comment: I have another segue called name3 which is exactly that. Gives the same error.

Comment: Can u make a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: Can you select your view controller with the segues in the storyboard, click on the identity inspector, and post an image of what it looks like?

Comment: @PhillipMills Added one.

Comment: Show image of your segue details.

Comment: Little bit strange here. There should be other Segue types (push with destination "Current" if you are using a NavigationController) - which options are in "Segue" ?

Comment: @derdida I added a picture.

Comment: Can u upload it to github?

Comment: @derdida this is the link :https://github.com/iamBlueGene/Chooze, also please see my edit.

Comment: Hmm still little bit strange. If i create a new project (simple with 1 Main and 2 SubViewController) and do the same things as you in your project, everything is fine and works. But i cant tell you whats wrong with your setup. Maybe try to create a new Project, working with a tutorial like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQXWsDNno8o and try out what happened when you have nothing (especially a very basic setup with just 3 ViewControllers) Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

When you set the Segue from one view controller to the other, ensure that you have correctly set the class - see image:

[image]

UIStoryBoardSegue was what mine needed.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you've already answered the question, I've provided an alternative solution for people who didn't find your answer helpful. Thanks for the down vote :)

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer my question, hence the down vote. I do understand that you like being a child and down voting me back :)

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you're looking for a segue in `ViewController2` but your question states that the segue comes from a button.  That would explain why it can't be found.

Comment: I'm not looking for a segue in ViewController2, I call this in ViewController1, where a button is connected with a  segue to ViewController2

Comment: Maybe the error message is wrong: 'Receiver (**ViewController2**) has no segue with identifier 'name2''  Regardless, if the segue belongs to a button, it's still not `self` as far as the view controller is concerned.

Comment: The View Controller also has a segue called name3 and the same errors appear when I try to call that segue

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the segue identifier ( name ), build ( cmd + b ), then set the segue identifier and compile. ( in storyboard of course )

Comment: And doing the same thing with your view controller name ?