# Receiver has no segue with identifier 'contact_segue'

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a problem that the `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("contact_segue", sender: self)` do not work and complain that **Receiver has no segue with identifier 'contact_segue'** even i have the identifier. I have used the SWReveal framework to build the left-side sliding menu which is work with table view(class: slidingMenuController). After I clicked the cell to call function changeView of MainNavigationController to do changing views.

```
import UIKit

class MainNavigationController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(false)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Home", sender: self)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "Contact_se" {

    }
}
func changeView(){
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("contact_segue", sender: self)      
    }
}
```

The changeView which is called by an a left-side sliding menu (class: slidingMenuController) in a tablecell:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let selectedItemMenu = arrayOfSlider[indexPath.row]

        let mainNav = MainNavigationController()

         mainNav.changeView()
    }
```

[image: Existing Segue]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cant call a segue in code (Swift)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023766/cant-call-a-segue-in-code-swift)

Comment: Maybe you are right, still working on it, thanks for your idea

Answer (score 2):

Just add this code `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("contact_segue", sender: self)` on your didSelectRowAtIndexPath? I believe there's no need for the MainNavigationController here.

Comment: no. there is a class (slidingMenuController) which is a left-side sliding menu. That class call the function changeView of MainNavigationController

Comment: oh i see. maybe because of the sender.

Comment: maybe, still working on it. Thanks for your comments. let me check the sender is the MainNavigationController or slidingMenuController.